# How to find out tuple whose attribute value is greater than all attribute average using an operator and AVG()?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called **Parts**.

```
+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+
| pcode varchar(10) | weight int    | color varchar(10) | cost int      | sellingprice int  |
+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+
| '1'               | 10            | 'Pink'            | 100           | 150               |
| '2'               | 20            | 'White'           | 200           | 250               |
| '3'               | 30            | 'Green'           | 300           | 350               |
| '4'               | 40            | 'Blue'            | 400           | 450               |
| '5'               | 50            | 'Red'             | 500           | 550               |
+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

> I need to find the pcode from this table for the part whose cost > average cost.*

I tried this:

```
select pcode 
from Part 
where cost > avg(cost) 
between 100 and 500;
```

Comment: Given your statement, why do you have `between` in the SQL ?

Comment: well removing it wont change anything, I thought giving it a range might change something.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks man, i had given up but then I made one last attempt, a simple try, it worked, I am like one day old to sql. I am just trying to do my assignment to prepare for my exams...

Answer (score 1):

Tried expanding more, it worked.

Average of column cost would be -

```
(select avg(cost) 
 from Part)
```

As required by the question, I need to find the tupples with cost more than average of the column.

which is got by simply placing the average value along with the operator.

```
select pcode 
from Part 
where cost > (select avg(cost) from Part)
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.